# Can I do a "for loop" with an awk '!seen[$0]' in there to apply in multiple .txt files?

Tags: for-loop, awk

I want to delete some repeated lines in multiple .text files 
I need to analyze each file independently, since they are not related to each other using:

```
awk '!seen[$0]' file.txt file.out
```

But when I try:

```
for f in *.txt; do awk 'seen![$0]' $f $f.out; done
```

I get an error:
The file '$f' cannot be opened.
Awk or '! Seen [$ 0]' is not recognized
Sometimes I get an output file but it's the same file ....

Comment: 1) You do not need the for loop. You can just do `awk 'program' *.txt` 2) Use quotes in your for loop around  `$f` 3) You are missing the `>` output redirection to `$f.out` which should also be quoted.

Comment: *I get an error...* is not a helpful error description. What exactly is the error message?

Comment: you are missing `seen` in `'![$0]'` and you probably wanted `'!seen[$0]++'` along with other issues pointed out..

Comment: something like: `for f in *.txt; do awk '!seen[$0]++' "$f" > "${f/.txt/.out}"; done`

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Right now we don't even know if you want to delete lines that are duplicated within each file or across all files.

Answer (score 2):

With NON-GNU `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk -v temp_out="file.out" '
FNR==1{
  if(prev_filename){
    close(temp_out)
    sub(/\.txt/,".out",prev_filename)
    system("mv -- \047" prev_out "\047 \047" prev_filename "\047")
  }
  prev_filename=FILENAME
  delete seen
}
!seen[$0]++{
  print > (temp_out)
}
END{
  if(prev_filename){
    close(temp_out)
    sub(/\.txt/,".out",prev_filename)
    system("mv -- \047" prev_out "\047 \047" prev_filename "\047")
  }
}
' *.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk -v temp_out="file.out" '                        ##Starting awk program from here with setting variable prev_out to file.out here.
FNR==1{                                             ##Checking condition if line is first line then do following.
  if(prev_filename){                                ##Checking if prev_filename is NOT NULL then do following.
    close(temp_out)                                 ##Closing prev_out file here from back-end.
    sub(/\.txt/,".out",prev_filename)               ##Substitute .txt with .out in previous filename here.
    system("mv -- \047" prev_out "\047 \047" prev_filename "\047")        ##Using system command to rename temp file prev_out with prev_filename(with .out)
  }
  prev_filename=FILENAME                            ##Setting prev_filename to current FILENAME here.
  delete seen                                       ##Deleting array seen here.
}
!seen[$0]++{                                        ##Checking if current line is NOT present in array seen then do following.
  print > (temp_out)                                ##Printing current line to temp file here.
}
END{                                                ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(prev_filename){                                ##Checking if prev_filename is NOT NULL then do following.
    close(temp_out)                                 ##Closing prev_out file here from back-end.
    sub(/\.txt/,".out",prev_filename)               ##Substitute .txt with .out in previous filename here.
    system("mv -- \047" prev_out "\047 \047" prev_filename "\047")        ##Using system command to rename temp file prev_out with prev_filename(with .out)
  }
}
' *.txt                                             ##Mentioning all .txt files here.
```

Comment: It works without the ">" to create the output file and even without the "++" in "seen", but only when it is for a single file.

I tried

for f in * .txt; do awk '! seen [$ 0] ++ '"$ f"> "$ {f / .txt / .out}"; done

As Sundeep suggested and it works. Sure it was because of the quotes Thank you very much!